# Compiling Gstreamer 1.10.2 from sources on debian

Tags: compilation, version, gstreamer

I have compiled gstreamer from sources on debian (raspberry pi) - version 1.10.2, but it still reports the old version and does not allow me to compile plugins -

```
gst-launch-1.0 --version
   gst-launch-1.0 version 1.10.2
   GStreamer 1.4.4
   http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/
```

Was it put into the wrong place?

Comment: Maybe try /usr/local/bin/gst-launch-1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous version (probably comes with OS) might be installed somewhere different than that you install. Such as `/usr/bin` (and `/usr/lib` for libraries) rather than `/usr/local/bin` (and `/usr/local/lib`). You might want to locate and remove the older versions.